# Node.js Error: connect ECONNREFUSED thrown by client

Tags: node.js, tcp, client

I have set up a node program (actually two, one for the server and one for the client) but I get this error from my client every time I run it:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

The code for the server:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
   console.log('Connection from ' + socket.remoteAddress);
   socket.end('hello world')
});

server.listen(7000, '0.0.0.0')
```

This works fine. As for my client code, not so much. Here is my client code:

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(7000, 'IP of server here'); // in my actual code, I used the actual ip, of course

client.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('Data: ' + data);
  client.destroy();
});

client.on('close', function () {
  console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

This is one of my first node programs, and it is my first using TCP, so expect a newbie mistake. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Does your server have a firewall blocking incoming connections on port 7000? This is likely the cause.

Comment: Does this matter if they are on the same network?

Comment: If it's a host/client firewall it would, for example Windows Firewall or LittleSnitch.

Comment: Ah. I see. It turns out that my antiviris software took control of that

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the "error" event to avoid the default exception throw:

```
client.on('error', (error) => {
    // treat error here
})
```